# What are some common ways to get sentence vector from corresponding word vectors?

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I have successfully implemented word2vec model to generate word embedding or word vectors now I require to generate sentence vectors from generated word vectors so that I can feed a neural network  to summarize a text corpus. What are the common approaches to generate sentence vectors from word vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding an `LSTM/RNN` encoder before your actual Neural Network and feed your neural net using hidden states of your encoder( which would act as document representations).

Benefit of doing this is your document embeddings will be trained for your specific task of text summarization.

I don't know what framework you are using otherwise would have helped you with some code to get you started.

EDIT 1: Add code snippet

```
word_in = Input(shape=("<MAX SEQ LEN>",))

emb_word = Embedding(input_dim="<vocab size>", output_dim="<embd_dim>",input_length="<MAX SEQ LEN>", mask_zero=True)(word_in)

lstm = LSTM(units="<size>", return_sequences=False,
                                recurrent_dropout=0.5, name="lstm_1")(emb_word)
```

Add any type of dense layer which takes vectors as inputs.

`LSTM` takes input of shape `batch_size * sequence_length * word_vector_dimension` and produces output of shape `batch_size * rnn_size`; which you can use as document embeddings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using python keras framework.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence representations can simply be the column-wise mean of all the word vectors in your sentence. There are also implementation of this like doc2vec https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html where a document is just a collection of words like a sentence or paragraph.